# Spin duplicate gives parts - how to spin a complex part of a pipe?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I wanted to get the stretching and pulling out of the mesh with using the spin tool.

The curve tool got used first but the stretching in highly bended areas was way to much.
With spinning it seems to only spin the selected loop.
Toggling the duplicate mode on in the spin mode, it doesn´t close the gaps between the parts.
how can this get fixed?

[image: spin mode usage on complex meshes problem]
[image]
[image]

The Bezier curve seems to ease the stretching but the optimal wished result in this case would be if there was a setting available to say that some parts of the mesh are stretchable and others are not.

Comment: I think the only way to do this array modifier + curve modifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Build the unstretch parts first, then bridge the loops among them:

[image].

Demo file for Method 1 is [**here**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25954).

**PROS:** Can well satisfy what you need in this particular case.

**CONS:** Quite a bit basic knowledge on blender is needed.

---

**Method 2**

Model stretching and unstretching units separately, then bend them individually with the same curve:

[image]

Demo file for Method 2 is [**here**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25957).

**PROS**: Relatively easy to accomplish.

**CONS**: Unavoidable intersections in final mesh.

Answer (score 2):

This method dosn't use the spin tool, however it will produce a similar result.

1- Create a mesh using only one segment of you pipe

[image: One pipe segment]

2- Add a curve

[image: adding the curve]

3- Add a array modifier to the single segment, changing the fit type to a "fit curve" and select the curve made in step 2. Then ensure the relative offset is set on the correct axies

[image: array modifier settings]

4- Also to the single segment object add a curve modifier and make it target the same curve as the array modifier. Play around with the deformation axis until it looks as you want it.

[image: curve modifier settings]

5- You're done. Remember that you still can modify the curve shape, in order to shape the pipe how you want it.

[image: Finished result]